# How to dynamically add a row to an existing table

Tags: php, sql

I cannot figure out a simple way of doing this

Say for example you insert something and a row doesn't exist, well I can manually add it.

This will save time for public database usages with creating database but it will build itself based on the inserted data after the rows are checked if existed.

How can I dynamically add a row to an existing table if the row inserted that is checked doesn't exist. So that no SQL errors will occur, as of a row that doesn't exist.

I will manually write this for php, but I have no clue on adding a new row to a table without creating a new table. Thanks .

Comment: I did not understand clearly what are you looking for? Why it is necessary to create table again if it already exists

Comment: add the code is must..thank you

Comment: @Amit I'm not creating a table, but adding a row to a pre-existing table. If i run a query with a row update that doesn't exist an error will be thrown saying "Row doesn't exist", therefor I want to check if the row exist, if not add it to the table then continue the normal SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add row then simply use the insert command in the php..

Insert command add the row..

```
$rs=mysql_query("insert into $table_name (name, pname, pcont) values ('$name', '$pname', '$pcont')") or die(mysql_error());
```

name, pname, pcont - these are column name.
$name, $pname, $pcont - these are variable used to store the value in the database.

Comment: If I do this will the table drop as overwrite in which I loose data?

Comment: no why you loose the data..??
the insert command every time added a new row in your table...
so, its no harm for data.

Comment: Ok thanks, just making sure. I never knew a this was possible. I thought if you insert another  table, same name an error will be thrown, but I guess you can insert a row using insert without corrupted any rows, and or data? When I insert, do I insert only that row I'm adding, or all the rows plus the one I'm adding?