# import products categories from XML

Tags: php, xml, xmlhttprequest

When I pull the categories, I want the same categories not to be listed, but it lists them all. I'll be happy if you can help me. Thanks.
XML File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
-<products>
-<product>
<product_code>AXX-655</product_code>
<product_name>Samsung Led TV</product_name>
<categories>Electronic > Home Electronic > TV</categories>
</product>
-<product>
<product_code>ACC-124</product_code>
<product_name>Fleece Coat</product_name>
<categories>Clothes > Man Clothes > Coat</categories>
</product>
-<product>
<product_code>ADF-147</product_code>
<product_name>LG 2103 Led TV</product_name>
<categories>Electronic > Home Electronic > TV</categories>
</product>
-<product>
<product_code>AXX-655</product_code>
<product_name>Sony Led TV</product_name>
<categories>Electronic > Home Electronic > TV</categories>
</product>
-</products>
```

PHP file

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file('xml/localxmlfile3.xml') or die("Error: Cannot create object");
foreach ($xml->children() as $child) {  
     $categories = trim($child->categories);
   echo  $categories."<br>";
}
```

**Output**

```
Electronic > Home Electronic > TV
Clothes > Man Clothes > Coat
Electronic > Home Electronic > TV
Electronic > Home Electronic > TV
```

**I Want**

```
Electronic > Home Electronic > TV
Clothes > Man Clothes > Coat
```

I intend to get the categories and subcategories separately. But it repeats as much as the number of products. I tried using the array_unique function and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to create a helper array to check the category is exist or not (`in_array($val, $array_name) //return true or false`)

```php
<?php 
$xml = simplexml_load_file('xml/localxmlfile3.xml') or die("Error: Cannot create object");
$category_helper = array();
foreach ($xml->children() as $child) {  
    $category_name = trim($child->categories);
    //if not exist in our helper array we add this
    if(!in_array($category_name, $category_helper)) {
        $category_helper[] = $category_name;
    }
} 
var_dump($category_helper);
?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. How can I get it one by one to add it to the database.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43406132/how-to-dynamically-add-a-row-to-an-existing-table

Comment: Thanks to you, I succeeded. Now I'm trying to download product images or get file paths in the same XML. I'm having trouble with the same name. Thank you.